# How to achieve the matrix rotations functionality python

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch the values after rotating the matrix , by using some input values we have to retrive specify index positons value

Here is my code:

```
def rotate90Clockwise(A):
    N = len(A[0])
    for i in range(N // 2):
        for j in range(i, N - i - 1):
            temp = A[i][j]
            A[i][j] = A[N - 1 - j][i]
            A[N - 1 - j][i] = A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j]
            A[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = A[j][N - 1 - i]
            A[j][N - 1 - i] = temp
    return A
    
m = int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(m):
    list1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
    list2 = []
    for j in range(m):
        list2.append(list1[j])
    matrix.append(list2)
rotation1 = input().split();
```

In my code i has rotated 90 degrees but the thing is , at the input it will ask many times to rotate ,after rotating the code and retrive the specific value

```
input pattern as
2
1 2
3 4
R 90
Q 0 0
Q 0 1
R 180
Q 0 0
U 0 0 6
Q 1 1
-1
```

here in above input R indicates rotation , Q indicates the retrival of index positon, U represents the updating of specify value

How can i approach this functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you have more manipulations on the 2D array and/or large data, I would advise you to use `numpy` for efficient manipulations. You can use [`numpy.rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) to rotate an array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
print(a)
print(np.rot90(a))
```

Output

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

array([[3, 6, 9],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [1, 4, 7]])
```

For clockwise rotations use,

```
np.rot90(a, -1)
```

The second argument is the number of times to be rotated.

Comment: Is that a view or a copy?

Comment: Ok, view would've been nice. I suspect the intention of the task is to make the rotations O(1).

Comment: If you are talking about time efficiency, then numpy would be superior. Also, the OP himself creates a copy on each rotation.

Comment: I'm talking about time efficiency, yes. Please explain how O(m^2) is superior to O(1).

Comment: I'm comparing it to the OP's code, not your idea of a view.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought you replied to my comment about O(1) being the goal (which is easy to achieve).

Comment: Nah. Maybe you wanna add an answer that might be suitable for the OP :)

Comment: Instead of using numpy I want an approach using python code? After the rotation of specific element.